# Каким способом можно изменить поле объекта ArrayList, зная только индекс? Много объектов с одинаковыми именами(

Tags: java, arraylist

```
class records{String name = "Paul";}
ArrayList<record> records = new ArrayList<record>();
...
```

Нужно изменить поле `name` с `Paul` на `Victor` в уже созданном объекте, который находиться в `Arraylist`.

Comment: и в чем проблема?

Comment: можешь написать, как достичь положительного результата)

Comment: Думаю вам стоит почитать основы программирования и ООП. Что такое конструкторы и в частности методы get’теров set’теров

Answer (score 1):

```
class Records {
    private String name;

    public void setName (String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Примерно так должен выглядеть ваш класс Records. Тут я присоединюсь к комментариям о том, что вам необходимо почитать об основах ООП.

Тогда ваша задача сведется у такому решению.

```
ArrayList<Records> records = new ArrayList<Records>(); 

Records rec = records.get(yourPosition);
rec.setName("blablabla");
```

Comment: к огромному сожалению мои умозаключения привели меня к ситуации, где имена всех объектов одинаковые и обращаться к объекту нужно либо через индекс, либо я не знаю. Подходящих методов я не нашёл

Comment: А как вы ожидали к ним обратиться по другому? Вы хардкодите поле name и ждёте разные имена? Ну и в целом в любом массиве вы кроме как по индексу не можете обратиться. Любой поиск подразумевает перебор элементов и сравнивание как-либо параметров. А если у вас все имена одинаковы, то вы ничего и не найдете. Ну или я совсем нет понимаю ваших намерений

Comment: к сожалению, не знаю, как автоматизировать выдачу различных имён для объектов, посоветуете что-нибудь? или перейти на обычный массив

Comment: Обычный массив что-то изменит? Ну есть по сути два варианта. Либо вы ручками задаете каждому элементу имя, либо вы пишете генератор случайных имен. У второго варианта много решений в зависимости от того какие имена на выходе вы хотите иметь. Для абсолютно случайных строк можно погуглить какой-то рандомайзер стрингов. Это не сложно

Comment: `Records` - множественное число. НО по факту хранится информация об одной записи. Следовательно класс должен называться `Record`.

Comment: Ну добавьте поле id. А вообще мне кажется у вас не правильное построение модели. Если у вас информация об одной модели то зачем вы создаете список ваших моделей?

Comment: Там может быть много объектов, насколько я понял, мне нужно автоматизировать выдачу разных имён объектов, чтобы потом обращаться к полям спокойно через имя объекта, а вы предлагаете рандомизировать заполнение поля name.

Comment: Я не понимаю вашей задачи. Вот и предлагаю решения исходя из того как я это понимаю. Возможно вам стоит переформулировать свой вопрос